# "zuviel" versus "zu viel"

Tags: spelling

I'm always uncertain when writing *zuviel* (or *zu viel*?). From my feeling I'd write

> Das sind zu viele Aufgaben.
>   Ich sehe zuviel fern.

Is this correct? And what is the spelling rule behind this? (And since the question doesn't yet meet the quality standards: It would also be interesting to know whether the last spelling reform changed the rules.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the spelling reform, the two word-version is the correct one ("zu viel"), unless you are using a noun as in "ein Zuviel an Schokolade".

Comment: Great, so I don't need to be uncertain anymore in the future. Do you know when _zuviel_ was used before the reform?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt in nearly any case, as Olaf stated, the one is the old form, the other the new one…

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: I think the rules were the same as for "wieviel": For countable things, it's "wie viele" / "zu viele", else it is "wieviel" / "zuviel". This is one of the things that became simpler with the reform.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Ah, thanks! So it seems my feeling above was right as far as the old rules are concerned. Do you know any reference?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: No, no reference. This is just what I learned in school.

Comment: Wie steht es bei "es wird mir alles Zuviel"? Ist hier die Großschreibung überhaupt "Ein Zuviel an Zuwendung"? Zumindest letzteres wird doch weiter zusammengeschrieben (und nicht etwa 'zusammen geschrieben').