# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "wieviel" und "wie viel"?

Tags: word-usage, adjective-ending

Die Frage stellt sich im Titel. Und auch, wann muss man eine Endung des Wortes benutzen?

Welche ist korrekt, und warum?:

> Wie viele Katzen hat die Frau?
>
> Wie viel Katzen hat die Frau?
>
> Wieviele Katzen hat die Frau?
>
> Wieviel Katzen hat die Frau?

Wann benutzt man die Endungen, und wann nicht?

Comment: Der einzig richtige Satz ist *Wie viele Katzen hat die Frau?*

Comment: @Em1 "Wieviel" ist aber ein Wort, oder? Wann kann man es benutzen?

Comment: Nein, *wieviel* ist kein Wort mehr. Es gibt noch *wievielmal*, aber sonst werden die beiden Wörtchen getrennt geschrieben.

Comment: Related: [“zuviel” versus “zu viel”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/zuviel-versus-zu-viel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Korrekt ist

> Wie viele Katzen hat die Frau?

(*viel* oder *viele* je nach Singular oder Plural des Objekts)

> Wie viel Geld ist im Topf?
>   Wie viele Gelder sollen wir denn noch genehmigen?

Aber man kann schon sagen:

> Wie viel Katze verträgt der Allergiker?

mit der Konnotation: Wie lange kann man einen Allergiker einer Katze aussetzen?

Oder:

> Wie viel Wolf steckt im Haushund?

mit der Bedeutung: Wie viel von den Eigenschaften des Wolfes stecken im Haushund?

Was man dann aber nicht mehr geht, ist

> Wie viele Wölfe stecken im Haushund?

Das würde bedeuten, er hätte sie gefressen oder anderweitig absorbiert …

Comment: Das ist so nicht ganz richtig. *Wie viel* kann man im Plural zu *wie viele* beugen, aber man muss es nicht. Manche Grammatiken versuchen subtile Bedeutungsunterschiede zu benennen, aber ich finde das wenig überzeugend.

Answer (score 0):

Nach dem Duden wird es "wie viel" geschrieben ([Duden: Wie viel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wie_viel)).
Deine Beispielsätze sind nicht korrekt. Besser wäre:

> Wie viele Katzen hat die Frau?

bedeutet die Frage, welche Anzahl von Katzen die Frau zu Hause hat.

> Wie viel Katze hat die Frau?

(so lautete der Satz bevor die Frage nachträglich geändert wurde!) bedeutet eine Frage eher nach dem Temperament oder der Art der Verhaltensweise einer Frau. Dabei wird auf das typische Verhalten einer Katze (fauchen, kratzen, schnurren, schmusen) zurückgegriffen und gefragt, welche dieser Verhaltensweisen die Frau zeigt. (Syntaktisch ist der Satz im Deutschen richtig, wird so aber im Sprachgebrauch nicht verwendet.)

Die anderen Schreibweisen von Dir sind im Deutschen falsch.

Es gibt noch die Schreibweise "wievielmal" oder "wievielemal" wenn man z. B. frägt, wie oft jemand etwas macht.

*Anmerkung zu frägt/fragt im letzten Satz:*

Gemäß Duden (siehe [fragen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fragen)) ist "frägt" landschaftlich, das heißt, es wird in bestimmten Regionen anstelle von "fragt" gesprochen. Laut Duden (siehe [starke und schwache Verben](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-01-04-11)) wird im Hochdeutschen "fragt" (seit wann?) verwendet.

Konkret bedeutet das, dass auch heute noch im Deutschen beide Formen vorkommen. Ich lasse deshalb den originalen Satz unverändert stehen, ergänzt durch diesen Hinweis.