# When to use ‘wie viel’ and when ‘wie viele’?

Tags: word-usage, difference

When should I use *wie viel* or *wie viele*? Is the difference in the genre or do they have no difference and I can alternate?

For example, should I say:

> Wie viel Sprachen sprechen Sie?

or

> Wie viele Sprachen sprechen Sie?

?

Comment: [Related answer to a different question in German](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/5421/15318)

Answer (score 21):

*Wie viel* is used for uncountable things like:

> Wie viel Reis ist auf dem Teller?

while *wie viele* is used only for countable things.

In your example:

> Wie viele Sprachen sprechen Sie?

is correct. Think of it as *how much* (*wie viel*) and *how many* (*wie viele*) in English.

Comment: Wonderful comparison stolen from the answer linked above: *Wie viel Wolf steckt im Haushund?* as opposed to *wie viele Wölfe stecken im Haushund?* ;)

Comment: And the same distinction applies to viel/viele.